# Why does my variable not keep its value outside of my loop

Tags: grails, groovy

I've been programming in Java for a while and I decided to try and learn Groovy. I'm going through the project euler problems and one the first problem I've already noticed something strange.

```
class Problem1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        def multiple = 1;
        for(i in 1..1001)
        {
            //if it is divisible by three then multiply is
            if(i%3 ==0)
            {
               multiple = multiple * i;
            }

            if(i%5 ==0)
            {
                multiple = multiple * i;
            }
            holder = multiple
        }

        println(multiple)
    }
}
```

my value to multiple is being set incorrectly. Everything works as expected inside of the loop but when I try to print my value I get 0. It doesn't even print the 1 that I set the variable to initially. I wouldn't expect this to happen in Java. Why does it happen in Groovy? I thought that groovy was supposed to be like Java under the hood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overflowing an integer (as you would in Java also)

Try using a BigInteger by changing

```
def multiple = 1;
```

To

```
def multiple = 1G
```